# JSF forEach loop values as method parameter

Tags: ajax, jsf, foreach

I think I have a somewhat easy question, I hope.

In my JSF page I use a forEach loop to create buttons to navigate through pages of a table. With ajax I want to render the table according to the clicked page. This looks something like this:

```
<h:form>
    <c:forEach begin="1"
        end="#{pages%1 == 0 ? pages : 1+pages-(pages%1)}" step="1"
        var="page">
        <ui:param name="pageParam" value="#{page}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="#{page}">
            <f:ajax render="testing" listener="#{properties.setPage(page)}" />          
        </h:commandButton>
    </c:forEach>
    <h:outputText id="testing" value="#{properties.getPage()}" />
</h:form>
```

As you can see, I try to set the page attribute in my bean. But when I click the buttons, I get an exception, that the method was not found (setPage takes int as parameter, but "page" is passed as Byte -> Exception: [...]setPage(java.lang.Byte) ).

So the question is, how can I pass the page number from the forEach as a integer? Is it even possible to pass each generated number to the correlating ajax?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
<c:forEach begin="1" end="#{pages%1 == 0 ? pages : 1+pages-(pages%1)}" step="1" var="page" varStatus="loop">
    <ui:param name="pageParam" value="#{page}"/>
        <h:commandButton value="#{page}">
            <f:ajax render="testing" listener="#{properties.setPage(#{loop.index})}" />          
        </h:commandButton>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Isn't this considered as nested EL? If so, this would not work.